# Can not understand the Exception after updating the table

Tags: spring, hibernate

```
27-Apr 13:21:35 INFO  CameraDetailsDaoImpl [] - org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: could not execute query; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [UPDATE cctvcamera SET police_station_name='T T Nagar  Police Station', url='', latitude=23.23528492, longitude=77.40121292, junction_name='Top N Town New Market Point',police_station_id=17 WHERE cameraid=2]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The statement did not return a result set.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.
27-Apr 13:21:35 ERROR CameraDetailsDaoImpl [] - updateAlertDetails() 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.trinity.admin.dao.cameramanagement.CameraDetailsDaoImpl.updateCameraDetails(CameraDetailsDaoImpl.java:119)
    at org.trinity.admin.service.cameramanagement.CameraSerivce.updateCameraDetails(CameraSerivce.java:33)
    at org.trinity.admin.service.cameramanagement.CameraSerivce$$FastClassByCGLIB$$4a96f69.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:617)
    at org.trinity.admin.service.cameramanagement.CameraSerivce$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8389c032_2.updateCameraDetails(<generated>)
    at org.trinity.admin.controller.cameramanagement.CameraManagementController.updateCameraDetails(CameraManagementController.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

my code:

```
queryUpdate="UPDATE cctvcamera SET police_station_name='"
            +list.get(0)+"', url='"+pojo.getUrl()+"',latitude="
            +pojo.getLatitude()+",longitude="
            +pojo.getLongitude()+", junction_name='"
            +pojo.getJunctionName()+"', police_station_id="
            +pojo.getPoliceStationName()
            +" WHERE cameraid="+pojo.getCameraid()+"";

        try {
            list1=getHibernateTemplateDCRMS().executeFind(new HibernateCallback() {

                @Override
                public Object doInHibernate(Session session)
                        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
                    Query q=session.createSQLQuery(queryUpdate);
                    return q.list();

                }


            });
```

Used Micro soft SQL Server 2008

Comment: i guess there is no cameraid=2 in table cctvcamera; post the code of CameraDetailsDaoImpl.java:119

Comment: show the code when you are getting this exception?

Comment: There is cameraid=2 in table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the response.

I got the solution, I have replaced my old code wit following code

getHibernateTemplateDCRMS().bulkUpdate(queryUpdate);

//where queryUpdate is query String

Answer (score 1):

Please use  executeUpdate method instead of use executeQuery to execute an update operation;

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are calling `query.list()`, this method is useful if you want to run select queries on your database.

Replace it with `executeUpdate` like this:

```
@Override
public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

    Query q=session.createSQLQuery(queryUpdate);
    return q.executeUpdate();
}
```